# how do I disable google play auto login in game maker?

Tags: android, game-maker

Am using google play services in my gamemaker studio game, I noticed that if a player isn't signed in to google play the game will keep asking for a sign in after showing interstitial ads or even when screen is locked and unlocked. I want the sign in popup to show only when user taps the right button. How do I stop the auto login popup?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Go to 'YourGame.gmx > extensions > GooglePlayServicesExtension > AndroidSource > Java' where "YourGame.gmx" is your project file. Now open GooglePlayServicesExtension.java with Notepad or any other text editing software. Find this chunk of code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    Log.i("yoyo","googleplayservices extension onStart called");
    //super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) 
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Now comment the if statement and the line of code inside it. So change it to this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() 
{
    Log.i("yoyo","googleplayservices extension onStart called");
    //super.onStart();
    //if (mGoogleApiClient != null) 
        //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Now save it (Ctrl + S). This disables auto login to Google Play Services at the start of your game or to be more precise whenever onStart() is called. Hope it helps for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The old ways of gm studio.

Go to gamemaker studio path >android>runner>src>yyandroidpackagedomain>yyandroidpackagecompany>yyandroidpackageproduct> and find gamehelper.java

Open in ms word and find these and change to this.

```
boolean mConnectOnStart = false;
boolean mUserInitiatedSignIn = false;

public void setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(int max) {
    mMaxAutoSignInAttempts = 0;
}
```

Note not working on run test must compile first.